# Series: Product of power and exponential

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, poisson-distribution, exponential-sum

I'm staring at

\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{ab^x} \frac{z^x}{x!}
\end{align*}

I know that without the exponential, this series would be equivalent to $e^{z} - 1$. Together with the exponential, does it still permit a closed form?

Comment: No, the closed form is very unlikely. Note: usually $x,y,z$ are used for real variables and $n,m,l$ are used for integer variables

Comment: @YuriyS if you could write up shortly how you come to the conclusion that the closed form is unlikely, that'd be a great answer I believe.

Comment: @ FooBar, closed form means that someone somewhere studied this kind of series in depth and they were interesting enough or important enough for applications that people gave the related functions and/or constants special names. Usually this kind of series obeys linear differential equations (exponential, trig functions, bessel functions, hypergeometric functions etc.), this doesn't look like it could obey any linear ODE and/or be interesting enough to warrant a special name